# Запуск консоли node в phpstorm

Tags: node.js, phpstorm

Осваиваю nodejs. Создал проект, установил yarn для node (через настройки шторма). Теперь не могу понять с какой консолью мне взаимодействовать, что-бы использовать node и yarn. Окно Run Command не подходит, Terminal вообще запускает виндовскую кмд.

Comment: а как именно вы собираетесь использовать node и yarn? И чем вас не устраивает cmd? если вы ожидали найти в PhpStorm Node REPL, или еще какую-нибудь специфическую консоль для node.js, то зря - ее там нет. Тем не менее вы можете запускать node.js приложения и npm скрипты через соответствующие run конфигурации, использовать встроенный терминал для запуска команд и проч.

Comment: см. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.1/installing-and-removing-external-software-using-node-package-manager.html, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.1/running-and-debugging-node-js.html

Comment: @lena https://youtu.be/8YamFtDEPZU?t=2m13s Я понимаю, что это маковский bash. Но с виндой, можно ли сделать нечто подобное?

Comment: интерфейс yarn совершенно не зависит от операционной системы и оболочки - все команды yarn , работающие в bash на Маке, совершенно так же будут работать в Windows cmd. Команды описаны в документации - https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/usage/

Comment: @lena Нашел в чем была проблема, виндовская консоль не видит развернутых в phpstorm расширений таких как Node и Yarn. Установил их глобально через инсталяторы и консоль их подцепила.

Comment: Маковская консоль их тоже не увидела бы:) если честно, не очень понимаю, как можно развернуть Node и Yarn в phpstorm, не установив их при этом с помощью инсталляторов. Может, Вы yarn добавили в качестве npm пакета к текущему проекту? Это работать не может и не будет